# How do I use PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to the PDO way of coding, how do I change the below code to PDO:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
```

Comment: [You should learn how to stand before you can walk](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

Comment: Tried one of the million tutorials online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get PDO enabled.

```
$query       = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
$total_pages = $pdo->query($query, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

You find everything you need here: http://php.net/pdo

Comment: thanks Jimmie for the help

Answer (score 0):

Edited
For example:

> ```
> $sql = "SELECT count(*) as num FROM $tableName"; 
> $result = $con->prepare($sql); 
> $result->execute(); 
> $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
> ```

Comment: Do you think table name could be using placeholder ?

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304 according to this you are fully right!